# C# library for working with STL files, both ASCII and binary

Tags: library, c#, 3d

I am creating a software for editing [3D STL files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_(file_format)) and I am looking for a C# library to do that. So far I've been able to find libraries that work only with ASCII STL files and don't work with binary STL files while i need both. I need functionalities like rotating, combining and saving of STL files. I managed to do what i need with python using the numpy-stl library, but now I want to move it to C# and I can't find something similar. All suggestions are welcome, thank you.